# Why r, h, and w aren't vowels

Tags: vowels, consonants

The `r` sound I can create (a) without moving my tongue (after it is put into place), and (b), without closing the mouth cavity entirely. Like `rrrr...`. To me then it seems like a vowel.

For `h`, it is basically an unvoiced vowel.

For `w`, it made by rounding my lips, like `one`. In that sense it seems like a vowel.

Wondering why they are considered consonants instead.

Comment: For [h], see the previous question "[Why is /h/ called voiceless vowel phonetically, and /h/ consonant phonologically?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4834)" For [w], see "[What is the phonetic and phonemic destinction between a semivowel and a vowel?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/25679)" For [r], see [Can a vowel be a consonant?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17751) and [Do some dialects of English have a liquid vowels, such as /ɹ/ and /ɫ/?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3912)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The International Phonetic Alphabet draws a very arbitrary distinction between consonants and vowels, and categorizes them completely separately. But in truth, there's not any major phonetic difference between `[w]` and `[u]`.

In actuality, the main difference between `/u/` and `/w/` is *`/u/` is the nucleus of a syllable, `/w/` isn't*. In other words, every syllable is a "vowel" in the middle, potentially with some "consonants" on either side, and this is the only thing that reliably distinguishes them.

This feature is called *syllabicity*, as in, "vowels" are syllabic, "consonants" aren't. Many languages have both a syllabic and a non-syllabic version of the same sound: if you speak General American English, you have six such pairs, `m n r l j w`.

The IPA encodes five of these pairs with separate letters: `j~i w~u ʕ~ɑ ɰ~ɯ ɥ~y`. For all the rest, you can mark the consonant with a line (`m̩`) or mark the vowel with a curve (`e̯`) to switch its syllabicity on or off.

Answer (score 4):

The letters [r,w,h] conventionally refer to "consonants", specifically, non-syllabic segments, whereas [r̩,u] refer to syllabic segments ("vowels"). Similarly, [j] is a consonant, [i] is a vowel – but [j,i] are the same *except for* that difference (and also, [m,n] are non-syllabic, [m̩,n̩] are syllabic). [h] is a bit of a problem because it has no unique syllabic variant that can be articulated on its own, nut in a sequence like [ha, hi], [h] is phonetically a voiceless version of the following sonorant segment, so you could transcribe "ha" as [ḁa], "hi" as [j̥i].

The terms "consonants" and "vowel" are confusing since they are used in multiple ways. Sometimes, "consonant" vs "vowel" refers to syllable structure pattern, in which case [h,r,j,s,l,p...] are "consonants" and [a,r̩,i,l̩] are "vowels" (usually nobody calls [l̩] a vowel but [r̩] is often called a vowel, in English). But if you are talking about the decree of constriction in a sound, then the terminology changes. This is recognized in some theories of phonological features sucha s the SPE theory, where "consonantal" refers to a particular degree of constriction and "syllabic" refers to syllable-structure function. So [h,j,w] are non-consonantal, but non-syllabic; [a,i,u] are non-consonantal and syllabic; [m,l,p,s] are consonantal and non-syllabic; finally, [m̩,n̩,l̩] are sonsonantal and syllabic. The standard definition of "consonantal" is "a segment with more mid-sagittal constriction that that of [j]".

Versions of *r* add one other complication. American English *r* is generally an approximant [ɹ] and not [r], and it is non-consonantal which can be syllabic or not. In other languages like Serbian, Croatian and Sanskrit, there is a syllabic version of [r], thus [r̩].